# c# winforms chart shows values wrong

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am using the following (really bad) construct to add values to a chart. I had no idea how to cope with c# using zero for "" so I, instead, checked if the values in the input are empty and use them as 999. So in the chart I check that value and if it is != 999, the points should be added.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lastDataInput; i++)
{
     if (dayData[i] != 999)
     {
          int j = i + 1;
          if (j % 2 == 0 && j < 4)
          {
               this.chart1.Series[$"Series{0}"].Points.AddXY("0" + (8 + (j + 1) * 1 / 2) + ":00".ToString(), dayData[i]);
          }
          else if (j % 2 == 0)
          {
               this.chart1.Series[$"Series{0}"].Points.AddXY((8 + (j + 1) * 1 / 2) + ":00".ToString(), dayData[i]);
          }
          else if (j < 4)
          {
               this.chart1.Series[$"Series{0}"].Points.AddXY("0" + (8 + j * 1 / 2) + ":30".ToString(), dayData[i]);
          }
          else
          {
               this.chart1.Series[$"Series{0}"].Points.AddXY((8 + j * 1 / 2) + ":30".ToString(), dayData[i]);
          }
     }
}
```

I thought an dayData-array like:

```
{22, 999, 999, 22}
```

Then would be shown as:

```
08:30    22
09:00    
09:30
10:00    22
```

but it shows:

```
08:30    22
09:00    22
09:30
10:00
```

If I hover during debugging at "Points" after it added the second value, it says 22 at X-Axis "10:00" - but that is not what the chart is showing.

Comment: just to confirm...is the array a floating point type?  you never want to try for an exact match on a float

Comment: the array is as following `double[] dayData = new double[20];` but I can also use int or float - the expected value is an integer all the time.

Comment: @HalbeSuppe if that's the case, then use `int`. your `dayData` values are currently floating point numbers, i.e. they aren't precisely 999, they are say 999.000000000000002, which != 999.

Comment: The x-values are 0 because you add them as strings. Usually you need to add them as number (or datetime). And without numbers they are simply set in a row, without proper spacing. Since they look like times add them as such and format the lables with a suitable format string..!

Comment: @aevitas i do something like `if(textBoxValueN.Text == "") dayData[n]=999;` so that should not be the problem :)

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. Comparing doubles for equality is tricky and usually a bad idea. Here is is extra bad ;-) - But the real issue is that you seem to expect to be able to place points at certain spots on the x-axis but have no values for their x-values. So they are placed as if the series was indexed along the x-axis. - Note that the string are just in the labels you see. Otherwise they don't exist and you can't use them!!

Comment: You could workaround by adding empty data points in an else clause, btw, at least if  the condition actually works ;-)

Comment: @TaW i checked the condition and it works. It works as expected until the point where the second point should be added on position 4 on the axis (if you count from 1) - but the point is drawn on position 2. I also checked the emtpy data points and tried different approaches around `Chart1.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, "Series1");` but i did not find any overload with let me define chartarea, series and value as I would need it. Maybe a little too high up for me to understand

Comment: _the second point should be added on position 4_ Nochmal genau lesen was ich schreibe und in dem Link auch! Es gibt keinen Grund den 2. punkt auf die 4. position zu bringen __weil es keine gültigen x-werte__ gibt! Aber der Workarund genügt vielleicht: `dieSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint() { IsEmpty = true });`